# How to detect wake word or if any word was said

Tags: python, pocketsphinx

Haven't been able to find a way to run the Pocketsphinx wrapper that should make it easy to know which words have been said

Some of the code provided looks pretty much just like this

```
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech

speech = LiveSpeech(lm=False, keyphrase='forward', kws_threshold=1e-20)
for phrase in speech:
    print(phrase.segments(detailed=True))
```

But nothing works and my terminal output says literally nothing. Just white space. How can I detect any wake word?

Answer (score 1):

My work around is to make the command that runs Pocketsphinx into a subprocess and pipe output into my python script.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, shell=True)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print line.upper(),
p.stdout.close()
p.wait()
```

The line that says "print line.upper()" looks like in terminal

```
INFO: continuous.c(275): Ready...
INFO: continuous.c(261): Listening...
A lot of various pieces of information
THE WORDS YOU SAID
```

This works in real time!